# Converting SQL Server 2012 to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2012

I've been using VS11 beta, which comes with SQL Server 2012. I also have a SQL Server 2008 R2 version of the `.mdf` file because the staging server uses R2.

I'll later be porting the project to SQL Azure. If I start making changes to the DB structure of the SQL Server 2012 version of the file, will it be possible to later convert it to SQL Azure later or do I need to make the changes to the R2 `.mdf` file as well to keep it in sync?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Azure is built on top of SQL Server 2012. You can use the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) to directly migrate a SQL Server 2012 database to SQL Azure.